# Shell scripts not running on double click

Tags: bash, scripts, sh

I have created the below script.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo echo "Hi, I'm root"
```

It is inside a file called `script.sh`

I have checked the permission to run as a program inside properties. When I double click, nothings happens. The only thing that happens is that the text editor opens. How can I see what is going wrong?

Comment: Thank you, but that is not what i wanted, I just wanted to make a script that runs something, it works now by enabling nautilus script run :)

Comment: OK, comment removed since that is not what you are looking for then.